# LinPhone SDK not supporting arm7s

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, linphone

I am new to ios application development. Now i am developing video calling application using LinPhone SDK. It's currently running perfectly in simulator. But, while i am building into the iOS device it showing an error

```
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Volumes/Work/Sample/liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/lib/libzrtpcpp.a for architecture armv7s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

If anyone know how to solve this issue???

Comment: Please ask a new question. The rule on Stackoverflow is that one question can only deal with one issue. This appears to be something totally unrelated to the original problem you were having.

Comment: i asked new question on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849263/error-occurs-while-runnning-app-in-iphone-4

Answer (score 2):

It's arm7s, not arm7 that your library does not support. Since the Simulator compiles to x86, the lack of arm7s support is a non-issue. On an actual device, though...

The solution is to go to your project settings, select Build Settings, click on all, then in the search field in the upper right type in arm. You should then see a line that says arm7 arm7s. Click on it and a drop-down menu will appear. Select arm7s and click on the small -. You have now disabled support for arm7s in your project, which should now build.

Comment: i got error while running it in iphone 4 . Can you please help me hoe to solve this issue...For issue please see my updated question..